# ipywidget interactive plot in Html presentations ipython notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I would like to use the interactive function from ipywidget in an ipython notebook to make a presentation in notebook.

I have stored my data in a pickle file and what I want is to change the parameters interactively so that I can see my plot.

My code is like this.

```
def spin(model, power):
    with open(path_cluster1+'SSHFS/Model'+str(model)+'/'+str(power)+'/spinpython2.pickle','rb') as f:
        spin = pickle.load(f)
    plt.plot(spin)          
    plt.title('Power'+str(power*0.1))
interactive(spin, model=(1,4,1), power=(70,101,1))
```

My collaborators are unfamiliar with python so in principle I would like to make the life easier for them to see my data just by changing a parameter in a html page.  Maybe I have to save all the data in a pickle file but the question is if this can work in a html without running python.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at https://www.nbinteract.com/. To quote from the website "nbinteract is a Python package that provides a command-line tool to generate interactive web pages from Jupyter notebooks."